# Uncaught ReferenceError: Component not defined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to display my Deal component but I keep getting this error below.

I'm using Meteor with ReactJS.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Deal is not defined
>       at meteorInstall.imports.routes.routes.js

Here is my routes.js file

```
<Route path="/deals" component={Deal} secure="auth" />
```

My Deal.js component file, that the route should be linking too.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import PrivateHeaderNav from './PrivateHeaderNav.js'

export default class Deal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <PrivateHeaderNav/>
        Deal
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

Am I missing something in the imports or in my Deal component?

Thanks

Comment: I think the error message suggests that Deal is not defined,  meaning it is not imported, if it is defined in another file. Can you post the import line in from route.js? If the import file path was wrong the error would have been different.

Comment: @GratusD. yes, I didn't import it in my routes file, that was the error, fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: ops didn't see that comment :)

Comment: @Sag1v No problem :) thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `routes.js` file is lacking the import of `Deal` component.
make sure you have this line in `route.js`:

```
import Deal from './path/to/Deal.js';
```